# UIImageView not loading sometimes

Tags: swift

I have a function that is loading a pic of the user from URL that is using this UIImageView extension:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {

        self.image = nil
        print("here the URL of the image", urlString)
        //check cache for image first
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) {
            self.image = cachedImage as? UIImage
            return
        }
        // otherwise fire off a new download
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)

                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Now, the problem I have is, that sometimes the the profile picture is loaded and sometimes not. I suppose that this happen because the function download the image asynchronously, but why once it's downloaded it doesn't appear On the profile?
I'm calling it with:

```
if hostPerfil != nil {
    if let photo = hostPerfil?.picture {
       hostPic.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: photo)
    }
    hostName.text = hostPerfil!.firstName
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Are you using the image view in either a table view or collection view?

Comment: nope it's a plane and simple UIImageView, there are two UIImageViews and I'm using the same method to load the opponent pic, and it's always loading.

Comment: Is `loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString` called from the main thread?

Comment: @Jan-Peter Vos yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the image from your imageCache, you need to set the image of the UIImageView within the main UI thread so that it will be rendered properly. You did that when you download it, that is why it is displaying, but you have to do it as well when you are getting it from cache.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) {
        self.image = cachedImage as? UIImage
        return
    }
}
```